# Assigning array variable in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm quite new to smarty template in php. I want to assign a value to a variable inside the smarty template:

```
{assign var=all_person_exams value={$gdao->getGrade({$val->getTotal()},{$smarty.session.schoolsection})}
```

The value returned by the method `$gdao->getGrade(...)` is an array. This method has been thoroughly tested without smarty. But, it's not working here. How do i go about it?

Note: it should have returned a value when i do something like: `{$all_person_exams.grade}`

Comment: Protip: You would like to do as much assigning of variables in your PHP-code as you cal, not the template itself. If there is any way you can avoid this cluster, do it. Also, parsing assignments like this is much slower via Smarty than in pure PHP.

Comment: I would have gladly assigned this in php code if it were possible under this circumstance, this's because one of he parameters to the method comes from within a value in the foreach loop where this assignment statement also belongs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{assign var=all_person_exams value=$gdao->getGrade($smarty.session.schoolsection)}
```

[Smarty assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

or even

```
{$all_person_exams=$gdao->getGrade($smarty.session.schoolsection)}
```

[Smarty short form assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign)